# If a power series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ then it must be to $0$?

Tags: calculus, power-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f(x) = \sum a_n x^n$. Let's assume that $f(x)$ has a radius $R=\infty$ and $f(x)$ converges uniformly.

Now, obviously $f(0) = 0$. Meaning, $f(x)$ pointwise converging at $x=0$.
Since we assumed that $f(x)$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, then it must be that $f(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$.

In short, if a power series converges uniformly, it must be to $0$.

Is that all right?

**EDIT:**
Here where the question is coming from:

> Let $\sum_n a_nx^n$, a power series with $R=\infty$ and $a_n \ne 0$ infinitely many times . Prove the series doesn't converge uniformly for $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Now, the solution starts with using Cauchy's criteria for uniform convergence. It claims that if we would like to show the series doesn't converge uniformly we want to show that for every $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there are $m,n > N$ such that:

$$\left| \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \right| > \varepsilon$$

Could you explain it please? My understanding is that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n 0^n = 0$. Meaning, the series **pointwise** converges to $0$ at $x=0$. So if the series converged **uniformly**, it would have been to $0$.

Isn't it right?

Comment: No. Why should $f(0) = 0$ hold in the first place? What if $a_0=1$ and all $a_i=0$ for $i>0$?

Comment: No: $f(0)\not = 0$ in general ($a_0$ may be nonzero). More importantly, uniform convergence deals with the convergence of functions rather than values at a particular point. Even if $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$, the function $f$ does not converge to the constant function $0$, uniformly or otherwise.

Comment: What? all terms are zeros of course: $a_n0^n$

Comment: I've added information to the questoin. I'd appreciate if you could respond to this..

Answer (score 4):

Almost. It must be a *polynomial*:

Given $\epsilon=1$, there exists $N$ such that $f(x)$ differs from $\sum_{k=0}^n{a_kx^k}$ by less than $1$ for all $x$ and  $n>N$. Especially, $x\mapsto a_kx^k$ is bounded  if $k>N$. This is only possible with $a_k=0$.

Comment: I've added information. Would you mine respond to the edit?

Comment: First of all, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k0^k$ is $a_0$, not necessarily $0$. Next, your argument doesn't use anything specific about power funcitons, so it would  - if valid - generalize to: If a series of smooth functions converges uniformly, then the limit is constant. A counter-example to this generalization is the Fourier series of a triangular sawtooth function, for example. Note specifically that the $>\epsilon$ in the quote you prove holds only for some $x$ (which may depend on $\epsilon$ and $N$ and whatnot)